# Permission to reference a Meta question on Meta.StackExchange

Tags: discussion

With regards to ["Stack Overflow Isn't Very Welcoming" especially [...] marginalized groups?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309513/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-especially-marginalized-groups), there appears to be a very clear and concise desire to get information on the following:

> Too many people experience Stack Overflow as a hostile or elitist place, especially newer coders, women, people of color, and others in marginalized groups.

I'd like to contribute the following Meta question to the conversation, [Apologies and parting notes](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2838/apologies-and-parting-notes), based on the following:

> I guess the TL;DR is that Stack Exchange has a culture problem, the experience for minorities who dare to talk about the minority experience is often pretty terrible. I don't really know how to stop fighting when presented with those situations, so untill the situation improves, or I learn to better deal with it, I shouldn't be participating here.

It appears this is exactly what is being requested in the MSE question. That said, I wanted to open the floor to objections for a few hours to bring up any objections, I can understand if we've already added enough fuel to this fire or if I'm misunderstanding the value the interpersonal meta post would provide.

Comment: I'm curious to know, what kind of reaction you're expecting to get from this? As you said, it's likely to bring violent reactions IMHO; I have trouble finding potential benefits from this.

Comment: I'm... a bit confused. Objections against what, specifically? Do you want to discuss the blogpost to see what we could implement on this site to make it better? Do you want to object to that blogpost? Do you want to object to something in the parting notes?

Comment: I'd like to give the mods and community a chance to bring up potential pros and cons to incriminating a handful of users on a relatively small site in the middle of a potential StackExchange-wide problem that will probably be getting a lot of eyes on it. I believe it's called the "Meta Effect?" If people don't feel this is even worth discussing, that's an answer in its own right and I'll act accordingly.

Comment: That question has already gathered 4 times the traffic of other meta questions of similar age, two community managers have already commented on it.

Comment: You never need permission to copy something from one SE to another. Everything is licensed so as long as you link to it, you're perfectly fine. As the only mod who's answered that question, you have my permission but, as noted, the CMs are both aware of it here and have shared it internally.

Comment: I would honestly be surprised if they weren't entirely aware of this when they were writing that post. It seems likely to me that it may have even been a contributing factor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One of the valuable things about apaul's post is that it *doesn't* actually point fingers at specific users. While those users may see themselves in what it says, they are not named. As such, I don't see much room for damage here, in that regard.

This site gets traffic from around the network already, due to the Hot Network Questions, so we're not unprepared to deal with this if it occurs, which (considering the number of sites you mentioned in your answer on MSE) I don't see this being a big draw of eyes.

As a technical matter, as I said, there's no need for permission. It's kind of you to ask and to let us know - thanks! - but we could not prevent you either way.

I hope [your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309538/369802) performs well. It seems well-written and balanced.

Answer (score 12):

I'm a little late to the discussion here, but seeing as how I wrote the post in question, I'd like to chime in.

**Feel free to use it as a reference, that's part of the reason that I wrote it to begin with.**

It seems that a number of people on the network don't want to acknowledge that there's a problem to be addressed, posts like that make it harder for those people to do that. And I'm honestly glad to have been a small part of Stack Exchange coming to terms and taking some steps in, what I hope will be, a better direction.